# How do I access the length of a square array in Python?

Tags: python

Say that I have an array map[x][y] where I don't know the height or width of the array. array.length() will return the overall height *width, but what if I want to know what the height and width are independently? Is that possible through python inbuilt utilities?

Comment: `array` doesn't do multiple dimensions.

Comment: Maybe post some sample code, because this question makes no sense as stated.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine you're trying to code some kind of game on a two-dimensional map.

Python doesn't have multidimensional arrays in the C or C++ sense *(which are, themselves, just syntax sugar around a 1D array.)* Instead, Python has lists, which are a **strictly one-dimensional affair.**

You can fake a two-dimensional array by creating a list which contains other lists. Like so:

```
width = 10
height = 10
map = [ [None]*width for i in range(height) ]
```

And you can get the width and height by:

```
height = len(map)
width = len(map[0])
```

This will only give the expected result if every sublist of `map` is the same length, i.e. if the `map` is a rectangular list of lists. Python will not enforce this restriction for you (why would it?) so you will have to enforce it yourself.

As stated in the other answer, `numpy` has true N-dimensional arrays optimised for numerical math.

---

Sidenote: note the use of the list comprehension `map = [ [None]*width for i in range(height)]` as opposed to the following:

```
map = [ [None]*width ] * height
```

which has unexpected effects:

```
>>> a = [ [0] * 3 ] * 3 #create a 3x3 array of zeroes
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[1][1] = 9 #change the number in the middle of the grid to '9'
>>> a
[[0, 9, 0],   # wtf?
 [0, 9, 0],
 [0, 9, 0]]   # wtf?
```

This is because the `[list] * n` operator for arrays doesn't make `n` new copies of `list`; instead, it makes `n` copies of a *reference* to `list`. Changing one of the `list` references will change them all.

Answer (score 0):

array is a single dimensional array. If you want multiple dimensional, take a look at the standard Python list.  See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Note that in the case of a list, you can get the "height" of the list (the number of "rows"), but the rows don't have to contain the same number of columns so you can't get the width directly.  You could find the shortest row, the longest row, the average row, etc, but you'll need to loop through the list to do it.

Depending on what you're doing, you might consider [numpy](https://numpy.org/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know python at all, but figured I'd take a look :)

Looking on this [page](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html), it looks like you're after `map.ndim`

**EDIT**

Hmm, it looks like i stumbled across a library called **NumPy**

**EDIT 2**

`map.ndim` in your case would be 2, ie - the number of dimensions in your array. `map.shape` will give you a tuple of integers describing the dimensions of your array. In your case 2,2 - so you would need `map.shape[1]` for the width of your array.

Comment: Those are the docs for `numpy.array`, which is different to the standard Python array type called `list`. Also it would be `map.shape`, which returns the size of the array in each dimension (i.e. `(10,20,30)` for a 10x20x30 array) as opposed to `map.ndim` (which returns the number of dimensions, i.e. `2` for a 2D array, `3` for a 3D array.)